# Codeigniter multi language url

Tags: codeigniter

Please help me. I search 2 hours but do not see any solutions for my case. My customer request me the multi language but they want the link as:

**http://site.com/controller_name/lang_code Or
http://site.com/controller_name/paramenter1/parameter2/lang_code**

The language code is always at the last segment. It is stored in the session. The url maybe also

**http://site.com/controller_name/ Or
http://site.com/controller_name/paramenter1/parameter2/**

In this case. The language stored in session will be loaded, but the url don't need to display it.

I try i18n library, but it cannnot solve my problem. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

In route you just need to ignore the language code so that it may not effect the Links and Form post.

```
$route['^fr/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^en/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^es/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^pl/(.+)$'] = "$1";
$route['^tr/(.+)$'] = "$1";
```

Also you need to make your base url such that it contains the language code, Then read the language code and change language accordinglly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this http://codeigniter.com/wiki/URI_Language_Identifier/.
If you would like the language code at the end you would have to change the route to something like this:

```
$route['((.*)/\w{2})'] = '$1';
```